# How to set an element height to be equal to window height using stylesheet?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want the `.Bck` `div` to stretch to the full height of the browser window. I've tried using jQuery, but when I resize the window, the height is doesn't adjust accordingly. What's wrong with my javascript and is it possible to do this with CSS only?

```
<!-- language-all: lang-html -->
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0'>
    <script src="http://www.iconight.it/js/jquery1_11_0.js"></script>
    <script>
    `window.jQuery`(document).ready(function(){
        `window.jQuery`('.Bck').css('height', `window.jQuery`(document).height());
    });
    `window.jQuery`(window).bind("resize", function(){
        `window.jQuery`('.Bck').css('height', `window.jQuery`(document).height());
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    body {
        margin: 0px;
        font-family: arial;
        font-size: 13px;
        background: #000     url("http://fc01.deviantart.net/fs15/i/2007/059/3/7/Drawing_Surface_Paper_Texture_by_Enchantedgal_Stock.jpg");
        color: #FFF;
    }
    .Bck {
        background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, transparent -100%, #000 100%);
        height: 100%;
    }
    #Section{
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        margin: 0px auto;
    }
    #Footer {
        text-align: center;
        padding: 50px 0px;
        width: 100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        margin: 0px auto;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 0px;
    }
    </style>
    <head>
    <body>
        <div class='Bck'>
            <div id='Section'>Hello world</div>
            <div id='Footer'>aaa</div>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: With right height? What is the right height?

Comment: `\`window.jQuery\`` produces a string in ECMAScript 6, or a syntax error in previous versions. So you can't call it.

Comment: @dowomenfart obviously he means the height is not what he is wanting it to be (which I think is pretty clear from his code).

Answer (score 0):

Remove the Javascript. Then, set a 100% height to the 'html' and 'body' tags on your CSS:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `vh` units:

```
.bck {
    height: 100vh;
}
```

**See in action:** http://jsfiddle.net/bu0qps4s/1/

**A few notes on your code:**

1. The standard is really to have lower case id and class names (so "bck" rather than "Bck")
2. @01dskoo1 is correct in his recommendation that you reset your html and body tags. Have a look [here](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) for information about getting rid of browser idiosyncrasies by resetting your css. I don't think it's causing you problems right now though.
3. Your javascript has a few issues:

   1. As has been mentioned, "`window.jQuery` produces a string in ECMAScript 6, or a syntax error in previous versions. So you can't call it." (thanks @Oriol). All your `window.jQuery`s could be replaced with just `$` (so; `$(document).ready()`)
   2. Your `bind` statement should be inside your `$(document).ready` so that it gets evaluated once the elements you are binding exist in the document.
   3. In jQuery `bind` is deprecated, you should use `on`

**Update:** To solve the problem you're having with lots of content in your `.Bck` div, you should change overflow settings so that `.Bck` is handling it rather than `<body>` (I've updated the fiddle as well):

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
.bck {
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but, if you replace "Hello world" with too div up until there is a vertical scrollbar, there is an issue..
<div id='Section'>
   <div>prova</div>
   <div>prova</div>
   <div>prova</div>
   <div>prova</div>
   <div>prova</div>
   <div>prova</div>
   <div>prova</div>
   <div>prova</div>
   <div>prova</div>
   <div>prova</div>
....
</div>

Comment: @user3433422 I've updated my answer to solve that problem (which was because of overflow). If it helps/solves the problem please upvote/accept ;)